# Is there a way to read a .txt file and store the values as a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is the .txt file I am working with:

```
Run,180,270,320,450
Jump,330,710,560,500
Walk,80,110,75,40
```

I understand how to store items as a dictionary if the `.txt` file only has one value to store. However, I am wondering if it is possible to store all items on the same line (in the .txt file) in 3 separate keys in one dictionary. Is there a method of storing the numbers as int values to the string keys?

I used the `.split()` method to return a list of all the words and then use the offset of that list to assign key and value pairs. However, I only get the first number from the file.

The problem I am facing is that the value in each key is only the first set of the list, and not the remaining 3 numbers.

My code:

```
exercise_dict = {}

for line in f:
    d_key = line.split(',')
    test_values[d_key[0]] = int(d_key[1])
```

The output:

```
{'Run': 180, 'Walk': 80, 'Jump': 330}
```

My goal:

```
{'Run': [180,270,320,450], 'Jump': [330,710,560,500], 'Walk': [80,110,75,40]
```

Comment: Could you edit the post and show how exactly the output should look like?

Comment: Looks like the remaining part is how to convert a list of string into a list of ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are only assigning the second element of the split list to the key. You should use `d_k[1:]` instead of `d_key[1]`.

To convert the remainder of the items to integers, use list comprehension: `[int(x) for x in d_key[1:]]`.

```
for line in f:
    d_key = line.split(',')
    test_values[d_key[0]] = [int(x) for x in d_key[1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed my issue.

Comment: You're welcome! If this solution worked for you, will you please select it as the answer?

Comment: Just to note, what @Nk03 did in his answer should also work (instead of using list comprehension): `list(map(int,line[1:]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. -

```
result= {}
with open('../test.txt', 'r') as f: # open file with context manager
    content = f.read().splitlines() # will strip any new line char
    for line in content:
        line = line.split(',')
        result[line[0]] = list(map(int,line[1:])) # converting dtype to int
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary.

In the below code the data has been stored in a file named 'test.txt'.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

exercise_dict = {row.split(',')[0]: [int(reps) for reps in row.split(',')[1:]] for row in lines}

print(exercise_dict)
```